# Dataflow job run without template creation

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to trigger a dataflow job without creating a template. It was possible a few years back but I am not sure if it is the case now.

Comment: Hi @Ananya, Could you have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator) ? also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run) for run dataflow job using **gcloud** cli. Let me know if this helps you or not ?